# Android deprecated Tasks.call - replacement

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-drive-api

In my android app I have an option to backup the database to Google Drive. For that I am using DriveServiceHelper class, but I just noticed, in Android 11 the Task.call is deprecated.

```
      public Task<FileList> queryFiles() {
    return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () ->
            mDriveService.files().list().setSpaces("drive").execute());
}
```

From my BackupActivity then I call `queryFiles` from `backup` method:

```
  public void backup(View v) {
        driveServiceHelper.queryFiles()
                .addOnSuccessListener(fileList -> {
                  // another code
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> showMsgSnack(getString(R.string.uploaderror)));
```

I did not find any solution how to deal with this to avoid complete rework of that class.

**What I tried:**

I tried to replace with runnable, also callable, but it doesn't work as Task is expected to be returned, not Filelist.

also I tried to use `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
public Task<FileList> queryFiles(int delay) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    new Thread(
            new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TaskCompletionSource<FileList> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();

                    FileList result = null;
                    try {
                        result = mDriveService.files().list().setSpaces("drive").execute();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    FileList finalResult = result;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> taskCompletionSource.setResult(finalResult), delay);

                    return taskCompletionSource.getTask();
                }
            }).start();
    
}
```

but the return works not from a method of void type.

Comment: Why not [the officially suggested option](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource)?

Comment: @Shark Can you please help with some example, in my question I added my attempt with TaskCompletionSource , but it can't be called from the main thread.

Comment: so why dont you wrap that in a Runnable, and have a future waiting for it? But that will also block your main thread... you should start executing these methods on background threads.

Comment: well, I tried it also with runnable, but from runnable I can't return the Task, as I suppose Task is expected to return as I call it from another class  driveServiceHelper.queryFiles()
                .addOnSuccessListener(fileList -> {... I realyy have hard times to complete this for weeks, would you be so kind to post some example that I can use for my case please?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, after hours of testing I tried this solution and this seems working for now: (using executorService, and in Handler a Looper is needed.)

```
public Task<FileList> queryFiles() {
    final TaskCompletionSource<FileList> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<FileList>();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    service.execute(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    FileList result = null;
                    try {
                        result = mDriveService.files().list().setSpaces("drive").execute();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    FileList finalResult = result;
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> tcs.setResult(finalResult), 1000);

                }
            });

    return tcs.getTask();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I meant something like this:

```
 public Task<FileList> queryFiles(int delay) throws IOException {
        Task<FileList> retVal;
        final FutureValue<Task<FileList>> future = new FutureValue<>();

        // now run this bit in a runnable
        /*
        TaskCompletionSource<FileList> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
    
        FileList result = mDriveService.files().list().setSpaces("drive").execute();
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> taskCompletionSource.setResult(result), delay);
    
        return taskCompletionSource.getTask();
        */

        new Thread(
                new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            TaskCompletionSource<FileList> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
    
                            FileList result = mDriveService.files().list().setSpaces("drive").execute();
                            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> taskCompletionSource.setResult(result), delay);
    
                            // and we replace the return statement with something else
                            // return taskCompletionSource.getTask();
                            future.set(taskCompletionSource.getTask());
                   }
        }).start();

       // And block (wait) for future to finish so we can return it, deadlocking the main thread...

//      return future.get();

      //FIXME do either this
//      retVal = future.get();

      // For bonus points, we'll do a timed wait instead -- OR THIS
        try {
            retVal = future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            future.cancel(true);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception "+e+" happened!", e);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception "+e+" happened!", e);
        }

    return retVal;
}
```

and that should set you on some path to solving the problem.

However, if the only reason for using the `Task<>` is just so you can add success/fail listeners to these methods - i strongly suggest you come up with something better that actually runs on background threads instead of the thread you're calling them on.

The FutureValue class:

```
/**
 * Implementation of {@link Future}, allowing waiting for value to be set (from another thread).
 * Use {@link #set(Object)} to set value, {@link #get()} or {@link #get(long, TimeUnit)} to retrieve
 * value.
 * TODO: tests
 *
 * @param <T> type of awaited value
 */
public class FutureValue<T> implements Future<T> {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "FutureValue";
    private static final long NANOS_IN_MILLI = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1);

    private volatile T value;
    private volatile boolean isDone = false;
    private volatile boolean isCanceled = false;

    /**
     * Sets value awaited by this future.
     *
     * @param value value
     */
    public synchronized void set(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        isDone = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public synchronized boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        isCanceled = true;
        notifyAll();
        return !isDone;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return isCanceled;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        return isDone;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public synchronized T get() {
        while (!isDone) {
            if (isCanceled) {
                return value;
            }
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                Log.w(LOGTAG, "We're just gonna ignore this exception: " + ignored, ignored);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public synchronized T get(long timeout, @NonNull TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {

        final long targetTime = System.nanoTime() + unit.toNanos(timeout);

        while (!isDone && !isCanceled) {
            try {
                final long waitTimeNanos = targetTime - System.nanoTime();
                if (waitTimeNanos <= 0) {
                    throw new TimeoutException();
                }
                wait(waitTimeNanos / NANOS_IN_MILLI, (int) (waitTimeNanos % NANOS_IN_MILLI));
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                Log.w(LOGTAG, "We're just gonna ignore this exception: " + ignored, ignored);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. If I do it with Future, then there are some problems as new FutureValue<>(); is not known, I tried to replace it with new Future<Task>, and also future.set(taskCompletionSource.getTask());  - set is not known command. If I tried it without Future, just with runnable (see my question update), then I am back on the start, I can't return taskCompletionSource.getTask(); from the runnable void.

Comment: You cant do it with just a Runnable - the runnable must set it's "return value" somewhere (which is why we're using a future) and you need to be able to wait long enough for a value to be set on that somewhere. Future can do both of those things, and is one of the two reasons it exists.

Comment: oh whoops, my bad, lemme add some more code here...

Comment: ah that is a class, ok. So after implementation of this all, when I click on backup button, nothing happens. After some time in console I have a timeout error Exception java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException happened and then of course java.lang.NullPointerException as there is no result. In my old code with Tasks.call after click immediately the backup was done on google drive in a matter of few seconds, but now for some reason it timeouts

Comment: then something else is broken. does the task even execute now? Have you considered using `Tasks.await()` without actually using this FutureValue?

Comment: yes, that's strange. I am debugging it, seems for some reason it is stuck obtaining the FileList      try {
                            finalResult = mDriveService.files().list().setSpaces("drive").execute();
                            Log.e("test3", "here");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }  as the test3 is never logged. Not sure why, because when I use the same thing with my old Tasks.call, it works

Comment: and also it should return then onFailureListener in my main class, not the timeout what user doesn't see. From 2 lines code with Tasks.call now it became too complex to obtain just one FileList from Google Drive, I think I will switch it back to Tasks.call which is working fine untill I'll find a working solution. Let's hope it just stays deprecated for more years. However thank you very much for your effort here! I appreciate it

Comment: i had a similar problem not that long ago and Tasks.await() was my quickffix :D

Comment: yeah, I am not very familiar where to use Tasks.await in my case, that's why I tried it different way - see my answer I posted. Not sure if it is the correct way, but at least it is working this way, just to encapsulate runnable in service.execute, using Handler with Looper and return tcs.getTask(); Maybe with Tasks.await() it is a better solution, but I can live with this as it works, didn't want to bother you again with another Tasks.await example :)